# How to send MQTT 'Publish' packet using (GPRS )sim900 modem?

Tags: tcp, serial-port, at-command, mqtt, sim900

I'm using sim900 modem with raspberry pi, I'm able to connect to server using AT command for TCP, but when I try to send mqtt Publish packet as follow(I used tcpflow to get this packet from mosquitto library):

```
Serial.print("0");
Serial.print("0x10");
Serial.print("0x0");
Serial.print("0x8");
Serial.print("ABC/XYZ");
Serial.print("HELLO");
Serial.print("0x0");
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: We will probably need a little bit more information to be able to help here. Are there any error messages on the broker side (assuming mosquitto run with -v to get more details)? Also rather than just using tcp trace the spec is available from here: http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_protocol

Comment: As @hardillb says, more details are required. Have you sent a CONNECT first? Is the above all that you have sent? Sending a 0 first (which would be the command byte) is never correct.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this  **[tutorial](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/2012/07/3g-internet-on-raspberry-pi-success/)** to connect internet on Raspberry Pi using **SIM900** modem. 
Download 'sakis3g.gz' from **[Here](http://users.abo.fi/fjansson/blog/sakis3g.gz)**.
Use  **[Mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org/download/)**  client library for **MQTT** pub/sub functionality.
It worked for me :)

**Steps to enable internet on 'Raspberry pi' using SIM900 :**

1. Enter this on terminal `sudo apt-get install ppp isc-dhcp-server usb-modeswitch`
2. Then download sakis3g from **[Here](http://users.abo.fi/fjansson/blog/sakis3g.gz)**
3. Unzip package using `gunzip sakis3g.gz`
4. Make file executable `chmod +x sakis3g`
5. Run sakis with GUI option `sudo ./sakis3g --interactive`

Now follow onscreen instructions. Good luck! :)